# Issue with too many redirects with python requests module

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I am trying to unshorten a list of roughly 150,000 t.co links and my code works for the most part, however, I have a bunch of t.co links that all redirect [here](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/take-action-end-autism-epidemic-and-implement-comprehensive-reforms-vaccine-safety-policies), and for some reason requests is getting too many redirects.

```
def expand_url(url):
  s = requests.Session()
  try:
     r = s.head(url.rstrip(), allow_redirects=True,verify=False)
     return r.url.rstrip()
  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
```

I tried using the line 
    `s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'`
as suggested in another thread. I also tried increasing the max re-directs and that didn't really help.

Here are some of the t.co links that are causing the issue:

https://t dot co/5FXvHY1Rbx

https://t dot co/L3Ytnz2916

Any suggestions on what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the max redirects times that you can bear.

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.max_redirects

```
s = requests.Session()
s.max_redirects = 3
```

the reason why you fall into deadloop because WH did not support head method, it keeps sending you `302 Moved Temporarily`. But actually you have redirected finished (from short url to WH). Try to use `r.history` to see all response

```
import requests

def expand_url(url):
  s = requests.Session()
  #s.allow_redirects = -1
  try:
     r = s.get(url.rstrip(),allow_redirects=3,verify=False)
     print([resp.url for resp in r.history])
     return r.url.rstrip()
  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)

print(expand_url("https://t<dot>co/5FXvHY1Rbx"))
```

Also you can write your own max_redirects.

```
import requests

def expand_url(url,times):
    s = requests.Session()
    times -= 1
    if not times:
        return url
    try:
        r = s.head(url.rstrip(),verify=False)
        location = r.headers.get("location").rstrip()
        if url.find(location) > 0:
            # in case redirect to same page
            return url 
        next_step = expand_url(location,times) if location else url
        return next_step
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)

print(expand_url("https://t<dot>co/5FXvHY1Rbx",4))
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that as mentioned in my original post. I even put it to 2000 and it still gave me a too many re-directs error.

Comment: use `get` to replace `head`

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Is get less efficient than head at all or they do the same thing? Cause I have to do it for 150k links, so efficiency is moderately important

Comment: i can not sure, but one more way is write your own max_redirects. I will post it later. @Flyrom