# Unable to scrape different plumber names from a static webpage using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape different `plumber names` from this [webpage](https://www.yellowpages.co.za/search?what=plumber&where=bryanston+west%2c+sandton%2c+gauteng&pg=2) for the last couple of hours using requests module as the content of that site is static and is also available in page source (Ctrl + U).

However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded {} redirects.'.format(self.max_redirects), response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

This is how I'm trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

link = 'https://www.yellowpages.co.za/search?what=plumber&where=bryanston+west%2c+sandton%2c+gauteng&pg=2'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.yellowpages.co.za/search?what=plumber&where=bryanston+west%2c+sandton%2c+gauteng&pg=1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Host': 'www.yellowpages.co.za',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    for shop_name in soup.select("h5.nameOverflow"):
        print(shop_name.get_text(strip=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make it work with `requests` but at the end I've used standard python's `urlopen()`:

```py
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

response = urlopen(
    "https://www.yellowpages.co.za/search?what=plumber&where=bryanston+west%2c+sandton%2c+gauteng&pg=2",
    context=ctx,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
for shop_name in soup.select("h5.nameOverflow"):
    print(shop_name.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Absolutely Fast Plumbing Co CC
Property Matters Gauteng (Pty) Ltd
Plumlite
Geyser Man
Daryn's Plumbing Services (Pty) Ltd
Electroc
Outek Engineers CC
Bryanston Plumbing (Pty) Ltd
Mage Plumbing & Electrical
Fourways Plumbing
Matrix Plumber
Angel Plumbers
Renovations And Maintenance Services
DCB Supplies
Call Us Plumbing
A B A Group
Action Plumbing
Clearline Plumbing Services
Capital Plumbing Supplies
AGD Plumbing
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you're getting this error is because when you're accessing the website via the link provided it is being redirected quiet a few times. Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365642/issue-with-too-many-redirects-with-python-requests-module), and let me know if that works for you

Comment: According to your suggested post, I could understand that I should set the max redirects times, as in `s.max_redirects = 3` or any number I wish the script to redirect. However, I included that line within my script above but that didn't really help to get the content. Btw, is this what you suggested?